# NextJS getting error on the first npm run dev

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I don't know what is going on with my PC but every time I create the NextJS application and run development. It will return this error

```
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[2]!./styles/globals.css
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
(node:20136) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_ISSUER] DeprecationWarning: Module.issuer: Use new ModuleGraph API
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[2]!./styles/globals.css
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\laragon\www\bayu-personal-website\.next\cache\webpack\client-development-fallback\0.pack_' -> 'C:\laragon\www\bayu-personal-website\.next\cache\webpack\client-development-fallback\0.pack'
```

I can't find any cause of this error on my project because it happened after I run `yarn create-next-app` and `yarn dev`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you add css file for some components ?

Comment: I was directly run the ```npm run dev``` and didn't do any modification on the project @H9ee

Comment: i dont know what are doing to install next js , but try to install this pakage : npm install postcss-flexbugs-fixes postcss-preset-env

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately it didn't change anything and still returns an error @H9ee I'll try again with yarn

Comment: Two things that I would try here: 1. Remove your next.js cache: `rm -rf .next` 2. make sure if you installed your project with yarn, then try to run your project with `yarn dev` (you mentioned running `yarn dev` in your question but mentioned `npm run dev` in your comment).

Comment: @elethan so far the result was the same. Removing the next folder and installing the project with ```yarn``` didn't solve anything, it returns the same error. Regarding the ```npm run dev```, I changed my question to using ```yarn```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to create the nextJS project on Users/ directory and it turns out to fix the error. Before that, I created the project outside of Users/ directory (directly on C: and create folder on there). So maybe it was a permission thing that make the project can't run.

Answer (score 9):

Create a `postcss.config.js` file in the root directory of your NextJS project.

Example code:

```
module.exports = {
 plugins: {
 },
}
```

Comment: It worked in my case, as is, even without any plugins defined

Answer (score 4):

I dont really know why, but I installed postcss-loader, css-loader and also created a config file for postcss, postcss.config.js and then the server ran successfully!!

try out that too, I think postcss.config.js is the problem

Comment: -del postcss.config.js

Comment: In my case, I forgot that I had installed postcss and was not using it. After deleting the postcss.config.js issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I got a very similar error while updating Tailwind from v2 to v3: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined`.  This was also caused by the `postcss.config.js` file, as others have suggested. I needed to remove `'@tailwindcss/jit': {}` from the `plugins` section.  My working config is now:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I was facing the same problem and i fixed it by restarting the IDE AND IT JUST WORK !!**

Comment: That was weird, but also that didn't work in my case. I have to change the directory project to make it work

Answer (score 1):

Need to create a postcss.config.js file in your root directory if it isnt there from init.

"PostCSS is a tool for transforming styles with JS plugins. These plugins can lint your CSS, support variables and mixins, transpile future CSS syntax, inline images, and more." from postcss Github

postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
 plugins: {
 },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same issue, and solved it by updating node version. At the time of writing, v18.16.0 is working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case i deleted the `postcss.config.js` and restart my server. I removed all the styling code in `global.css` except `@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;`  . It works and compiled successfully for my device.

Answer (score 1):

While using NextJs with tailwind, I had this error logging in the console, which led me to this thread:

```
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[2]!./styles/index.css Warning (1:1) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.
```

Then I checked my terminal, where I found this error:

```
warn - As of Tailwind CSS v3.3, the `@tailwindcss/line-clamp` plugin is now included by default.
warn - Remove it from the `plugins` array in your configuration to eliminate this warning.
warn  - ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[2]!./styles/index.css
Warning

(1:1) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.
```

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72511039/autoprefixer-replace-color-adjust-to-print-color-adjust-the-color-adjust-short), which led me to upgrade some packages as recommended by icc97[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73934838/17767334)

```
yarn add --dev tailwindcss@latest \
  @tailwindcss/typography@latest \
  @tailwindcss/forms@latest \
  @tailwindcss/aspect-ratio@latest \
  @tailwindcss/line-clamp@latest \
  postcss@latest \
  autoprefixer@latest
```

This resolved the error, but I wanted to test to see if I could recreate the error in order to push a fix to my repo.
But when I deleted `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`, ran a `yarn cache clean` and a `yarn install`, the error didn't reappear.
It seems that just running the above upgrade, despite removing them right after, fixed the issue. **I welcome any explanations by anyone more experienced than me :)**

Answer (score 0):

1. Run this command in CLI  : npm install postcss-flexbugs-fixes postcss-preset-env --save-exact
2. in postcss.config.js file , write following code:

```js
    module.exports={
            "plugins" :[
              "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
              [
                "postcss-preset-env",
                {
                  "autoprefixer": {
                    "flexbox": "no-2009"
                  },
                  "stage": 3,
                  "features": {
                    "custom-properties": false
                  }
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
```

and you are done ... this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had uninstalled tailwindcss but forgot to delete it from `postcss.config.js`, so I delete it from there too, then I delete .next folder & it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I fix same error by adding double quotation marks to fields in postcss.config.js:

module.exports = {
plugins: [
"tailwindcss",
"postcss-nesting",
"autoprefixer"
]
}

Answer (score 0):

Change what you have in your tailwind.config.js to

```
*plugins: [
 require('@tailwindcss/forms/src/index'),
],*
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating node version up to the latest LTS worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this issue, even though I have a postcss.config.js, and I resolved it by simply switching to the latest version of Node. In my case, it was version 18.12.0.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35116835)