# autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, npm, postcss, autoprefixer

I installed `autoprefixer` and I get this warning:

```bash
npm install autoprefixer@10.4.5 --save-exact
```

> `WARNING in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`
> `(./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)`
> `Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):`
> `Warning`
>
> `autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.`
>
> `webpack compiled with 1 warning`

Comment: Could you tell us what research you have done? For example, there are a lot of comments about this here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36259 You may just need to use a more recent version.

Comment: I tried by installing this then also I am getting the problem

npm install autoprefixer@10.4.5 --save-exact

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJs - Compiled with warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72108482/reactjs-compiled-with-warning)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Add following line in `package.json`:

If you're using **yarn**:

```
"resolutions": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
}
```

If you're using **npm**:

```
"overrides": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
}
```

Comment: Worked!

If it helps, here's the discussion in GitHub: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36259

Comment: Also needed to delete `node_modules` and `yarn-lock.json`, and run `yarn` again

Answer (score 33):

The solution was to install bootstrap 5.2 beta using the command

```
npm install bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1
```

Answer (score 16):

This issue is because of **Autoprefixer v10.4.6**+ `color-adjust` **deprecation** and it's replaced with `print-color-adjust`. It's currently fixed by *Bootstrap v5.2.0-beta1*. So you can update your *Bootstrap* version:

```
npm i bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1
```

---

Or, just override **Autoprefixer** plugin and **downgrade** it to previous version *"10.4.5"*:

1. In *package.json* of your react app, add the following section after the `dependencies: {...}`

```
"overrides": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
 }
```

2. Run the command `npm install`
3. And finally `npm start`

Answer (score 12):

I came across this error but unrelated to Bootstrap. It was with Next.js / Tailwind CSS.

I was getting this error:

```
warn  - ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[2]!./src/styles/globals.css
Warning
(1:1) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[2]!./src/styles/globals.css
```

As part of the [Next.js tailwind installation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs), tailwind suggests installing with `postcss` and `autoprefixer`.

I had updated the `postcss` and `autoprefixer` npm packages, but I was still getting this error.

To fix it I needed to update all of the tailwind plugins.

Here is an example of how to [upgrade the tailwind css plugins](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#official-plugins), this is doing the whole tailwind installation:

```bash
npm install --save-dev tailwindcss@latest \
  @tailwindcss/typography@latest \
  @tailwindcss/forms@latest \
  @tailwindcss/aspect-ratio@latest \
  @tailwindcss/line-clamp@latest \
  postcss@latest \
  autoprefixer@latest
```

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade bootstrap to 5.2.0-beta1 by running the following command:

```
npm install bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1
```

Source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36259#issuecomment-1143073964

Answer (score 0):

For Rush.js users, you'll want to add these to your `common/config/rush/common-versions.json`:

```json
  "preferredVersions": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5",
    "postcss-preset-env": "7.4.3"
  },
```

because the latest version of `postcss-preset-env` (which is in turn required by `react-scripts: "5.0.0"`) requires `"autoprefixer": "10.4.5"`

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
yarn add bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I think this error is because of the existence of both bootstrap and tailwind.

**I just remove bootstrap, and the error disappears.**

Answer (score -1):

My solution was the next but i use Tailwind not Bootstrap, maybe someone have my same issue:

```
npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest @tailwindcss/forms@latest
```

Comment: Same as with my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73934838/327074

Answer (score -1):

npm install bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1 worked for me

Answer (score -1):

If you need a solution with no need to touch the package.json or upgrade/downgrade autoprefixer , or remove bootstrap follow the steps:

1. search in vs code for color-adjust
2. it will find it in yours *.css files you wrote* (**not in node modules folder**)
3. replace it with print-color-adjust and save all the changed files

example :

```
before:

-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
color-adjust: exact;

after:
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
print-color-adjust: exact;
```

Answer (score -2):

Go to `./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` and Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust and enter code here and type
`npm install autoprefixer@10.4.5 --save-exact` This worked for me

Answer (score -11):

go to \node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css, usually in the line 2482, edit

> color-adjust: exact;

to

> print-color-adjust: exact;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Whatever is in node_modules shouldn't be edited since these files should always be fetched using the `npm install` command in another environment...