# react-bootstrap - autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, autoprefixer

Im currently using npm and ive seen the limited articles stating how
`npm install autoprefixer@10.4.5 --save-exact`
has solved this problem. I'm still having some trouble as this error is still displayed even after installing `autoprefixer@10.4.5`.

Any ideas how to combat?

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
  },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72511039/autoprefixer-replace-color-adjust-to-print-color-adjust-the-color-adjust-short)

Answer (score 0):

If you use npm, use "overrides" (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides):

```
{
  "overrides": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
  }
}
```

If you use yarn, it is called "resolutions": https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/

Comment: so this goes in packages.json under dependencies