# Some TailwindCSS classes in a fresh Laravel install is not working

Tags: php, laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-9

Some TailwindCSS classes that involve color (namely `bg` and `border`) are not working.

This is my very first Laravel project and I am not sure where the problem is. Somebody else started the project and I cloned the git repository. I am developing locally on a Ubuntu 22.04 desktop box with Apache2 -v 2.4.54 and php -v 8.0.20. I got Laravel working weeks ago and spent all my time getting data on screen. Now I am trying to beautify my pages. I did not know that you had to install TailwindCSS seperately from Laravel so I installed it yesterday. I installed npm and TailwindCSS via `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`.  `Tailwind.config.js`, `webpack.mix.js` and `/resources/css/app.css`  were already a part of my git repo and appear to normal. 
**Question**: If you already have the needed files, is 'npx tailwindcss init` necessary (my init fails with a yaml error)?

I think TailwindCSS is working some, but I am not entirely sure. I added `bg` classes to the man Laravel and it seems to totally skip the class any `bg` and `border` classes I add.

I did have have the color-adjust warning when I ran `npm run dev`, but was able to get rid of it by targeting the a specific autoprefixer version.
[autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72511039/autoprefixer-replace-color-adjust-to-print-color-adjust-the-color-adjust-short)

I added the `bg-blue-500` class several places, but nothing seems to work. There are other tw classes that appear to be working.
**Question:** What would cause these classes to be totally ignored? Did I miss something in the install?

[image]

Comment: delete your css file and see if it is rebuilt.  Check that its the one being loaded in the head.

Comment: there are two app.css files in my project. One in `./public/css/app.css` and other in `./resources/css/app.css`. `nvm run dev` whined when the resource one was moved, so I put it back. The public one was recreated and the `bg-blue-500` directive is in it. But still not working.

Comment: When I checked the css in the head, my `bg-blue-500` was not in it. I changed my view to use a class that was already present and it worked. I changed it back and rebuilt the public css and my original code and class are now present and working. Don't know what changed. This is complicated and confusing...

Comment: Somewhere in this multi-step operation, I cleared the browser cache, maybe that was the missing ingredient!

Comment: normally when your browser developer tools are open, browser cache is disabled.  Not sure about firefox - look for a checkbox to disable cache.

Comment: files in your resources folder are not externally accessible. These are the source for the built classes and js files which are then created in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the welcome page as an example. It contains all the tailwind styles it needs locally (in the head) on the page.  Experiment with one of the internal pages.

Comment: changed the picture out to one of my internal pages.